# Different URI from ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I've included in my app the possibility to insert content with the "share with" button from the  phone gallery, but in different devices i have different results. For example, if i retrieve the uri of the content from the Intent with the code

```
  val fileUri: Uri =  intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM).asInstanceOf[Uri]
```

in galaxy S3 I have: `content://media/external/images/media/812`
and in nexus 7 I have: `file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/ContactPhoto-IMG_20131119_173230.jpg`

if i use the function:

```
val projection: Array[String] = Array(MediaColumns.DATA)
val cursor :Cursor= act.getContentResolver.query(uri,projection,null,null,null)
val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA)
cursor.moveToFirst()
cursor.getString(column_index)
```

in this two different type of Uri, the second one give me error because the cursor is `null`

The problem is that sometimes the action_send is coming with a file:\ URI, and sometimes with a content:\ URI. And I need to spot file:\ and convert it to a content one.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to have the same Uri structure in all the devices?

Other apps are welcome to send whatever `Uri` values that they want. If your `<intent-filter>` says that you support those schemes, you will get those `Uri` values and have to deal with them.

Note that you should not be using your code snippet anyway. There is no requirement that any `Uri` that is given to you be in the `MediaStore`.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes the action_send is coming with a file:\\ URI, and sometimes with a content:\\ URI. And i need to spot file:\\ and convert it to a content one.

Comment: @user3793870: You are welcome to create your own `ContentProvider` that serves up files from `file://` `Uri` values. You cannot "convert" a `file://` scheme into a `content://` scheme by any other means, just as you cannot convert an `http://` URL into an `ftp://` URL on the Internet. You might wish to explain why you think you need to convert the `Uri` this way -- after all, you do not need to do that to get at the content of the file.